# Automatically Generated Types Not Being Exported in the build??? (export keyword)

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, rollup

> If you guys wish to see the generated code, it's [@vertical-insure/web-components@3.1.17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vertical-insure/web-components?activeTab=code).

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to deal with: exporting my package's transpiled functionalities as well as its types (and later publishing it to NPM).

So far, I have a configuration that successfully and automatically exports and publishes both the exported functionalities as well as its types. Only none of the types in the `index.d.ts` file have any `export` in front of them, so I can't access them externally.

I think this is because I'm failing to understand how this process works. For example, in my `index.ts` file, I thought I could list types as well, and then have TypeScript deal with segregating TS stuff from the transpiled JS functionalities. However, that doesn't seem to be how it works.

Anyways, here is the summary of my configuration...

In my `tsconfig.json`, I use these to export my declaration files into the `build/dts` folder:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "build/dts"
  }
}
```

I'm using Rollup to then stack them all together on `build/index.d.ts`:

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default [
  {
    input: ['src/index.ts'],
    ...
    plugins: [
      ...
      typescript({
        declarationDir: 'build/dts',
      }),
    ],
  },
  ...
  {
    input: './build/dts/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'build/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

What am I missing in order to be able to export my types? Are there any more steps I need to take in order to be able to use both the transpiled JS functionalities and the types from external packages?

> If you guys wish to see the generated code, it's [@vertical-insure/web-components@3.1.17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vertical-insure/web-components?activeTab=code).

Comment: I've basically ditched Rollup so far. The build all works then, the only thing is that the `web-dev-server` can't handle the `package.json`'s `"type": "module"`.